# ionic 4 file chooser not allowing to select multiple files

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm new to Ionic. I wanted to select multiple images from the gallery and send to the server.

I'm using Ionic 4 "File Chooser" (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser) to select files and "File Transfer" to transfer file. From the "file chooser" I can select ONLY one file. But I wanted to select multiple files ( multiple images ).

Is this possible? If not what are the alternative solutions to select multiple images from the Gallery to transfer to the server.

There should be a solution for this as this is a common scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alternative you should check out `Image Picker` which lists itself as:

> Cordova Plugin For Multiple Image Selection

You can see it here

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker

Seems usage is straightforward:

```
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker/ngx';


constructor(private imagePicker: ImagePicker) { }

...

this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
  }
}, (err) => { });
```

Comment: yes... it worked... but it got crashed... and I followed https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/issues/86 to fix... thanks alot